# Ignoring dictionary value while using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm trying to ask a question to a database using requests and display the answer in Excel file using openpyxl. The goal is to put keys in row 1 and corresponding values row 2. I figured how to do this most of the time, problem starts when value has lists and/or other dictionaries inside. 
Obviously the database is confidential, so I have tried really hard to create similar example without any sensitive data. It's done by hand, so please ignore any obvious mistakes on my part:

```
   ###the results of requests.get, pretified by hand###
{'name' : 'Kate', 'surname': 'Smith', 'number' : '1', 'age' : '8', 'relations' : 
    { 
    'parents' : 
                [
                {'name' : 'Mary', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '2', 'age' : '32'}, 
                {'name' : 'Peter', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '3', 'age' : '33'}
                ], 
    {
    'friends' : 
                [
                {'name' : 'Susan', 'surname' : 'Brown', 'number' : '4', 'age' : '9'}, 
                {'name' : 'John', 'surname' : 'Spencer', 'number' : '5', 'age' : '9'}
                ]
    }
    }
}

###the relevant part of code###
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "Kate and friends"
x = 0
y = 0
for i in response.keys():
    if i != 'relations':
        ws1.cell(row=x + 1, column=y + 1, value=i)
        ws1.cell(row=x + 2, column=y + 1, value=response[i])
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1

wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

The error I would get in this case would be:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert { 'parents' : [{'name' : 'Mary', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '2', 'age': '32'}, {'name' : 'Peter', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '3', 'age' : '33'}], {'friends' : [{'name' : 'Susan', 'surname' : 'Brown', 'number' : '4','age' : '9'}, {'name' : 'John', 'surname' : 'Spencer', 'number' :'5','age' : '9'}]}}} to Excel
```

It is understandable that Openpyxl does not want to put lists or dictionaries in single cell. As you probably see I'm trying to tell openpyxl: ' Do what you usually do, just ignore the 'relations' key and corresponding value', yet it ignores me and tries to squeeze nested objects inside a cell. Can anyone please show me how to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary you have supplied is not valid Python. Please check your `response` dictionary.

As such, if your dictionary is correctly formed as below, you will find no problem:

```
d = {'name' : 'Kate', 'surname': 'Smith', 'number' : '1', 'age' : '8', 'relations' : 
    { 
    'parents' : 
                [
                {'name' : 'Mary', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '2', 'age' : '32'}, 
                {'name' : 'Peter', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'number' : '3', 'age' : '33'}
                ], 
    'friends' : 
                [
                {'name' : 'Susan', 'surname' : 'Brown', 'number' : '4', 'age' : '9'}, 
                {'name' : 'John', 'surname' : 'Spencer', 'number' : '5', 'age' : '9'}
                ]
    }}

for i in d.keys():
    if i != 'relations':
        print(i, d[i])

# name Kate
# surname Smith
# number 1
# age 8
```

Comment: @Mr_Happy, no problem. Does that solve your problem? If it does, feel free to accept (green tick on left) so others know your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the dictionary. As for the question I have no problems with telling Python what to print. Just tested your code with the original dict and it works as intended. The issue is rather with openpyxl. It complains about values containing nested disctionaries, seemingly oblivious to fact that I told it to ignore those.

Comment: I see, I'd like to be able to replicate but seems hard.. from the code in my answer `ws1.cell(row=x + 1, column=y + 1, value=i)` will never be reached with `i == 'relations'`. So I'm not sure how you get to that stage with your code.

Comment: And that was the answer ! :) The code never reach the instruction that tells it to ignore part of the dict (not that I understand why, but fine, now I can at least work around it). Ok, I will just re-write it to remove sensitive part before it starts to populate Excel file. Thank you jpp, thanks to you I am able to continue with my work :)